# Npm error "internalBinding is not defined"

Tags: node.js, npm

I had some problems with gulp installing and through the time i have got some "npm install" error [npm install error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQRzN.png)

npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'npm' ]
2 info using npm@3.6.0
3 info using node@v11.12.0
4 verbose stack ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined
4 verbose stack     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:25:1
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
4 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:3:27)
5 verbose cwd /home/michael
6 error Linux 4.15.0-46-generic
7 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm"
8 error node v11.12.0
9 error npm  v3.6.0
10 error internalBinding is not defined
11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
11 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: can you try `npm install natives@1.1.6`

Comment: appears the same error

Comment: @MichaelDaineka did you upgrade your node version recently? If so, try `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`. This will download and build your native modules against the new node version. See https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2246

Comment: @TomM and the same error appears

Comment: If you installed gulp globally, then `npm install -g natives@1.1.6` could help. This will install the natives globally too.

Comment: @TomM i just can't do anything with npm, it appears error even if npm install <smt package>

Comment: Well, then your best bet would be to un/reinstall nodejs and npm If that's possible.

Comment: @TomM it isn't help, i have been trying for 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

Then choose the right version of the nodejs:

```
nvm install 11
```

Also to clear configs:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/[username]/.config
```